# ZSH: Output from stdout from within while read gets lost

Tags: shell, zsh

I ran into a weird ZSH issue. I have trimmed the script to the smallest form that still reproduces the issue.

What I'm simulating here, is monitoring a directory for changes via a subprocess (the actual script uses `fswatch`). Because I'm monitoring, it means I cannot run a command beforehand and save the output. A (working) example is the following:

```sh
(echo "text.txt"; echo "text.txt") | while read filepath; do scp "$filepath" "trip:~/tom/"; echo $?; done
text.txt                    100%  822    51.1KB/s   00:00
0
text.txt                    100%  822    99.1KB/s   00:00
0
```

Now, when I add a delay in the middle, seemingly any delay that is longer than the runtime of the `scp` command inside the while-loop, suddenly the second output and any subsequent command of `scp` will not visible:

```sh
(echo "text.txt"; sleep 2; echo "text.txt") | while read filepath; do scp "$filepath" "trip:~/tom/"; echo $?; done
text.txt                    100%  822    51.1KB/s   00:00
0
0
```

Interestingly enough, the `echo` still works and errors show up like you may expect.

```sh
(echo "doesnotexist.txt"; sleep 2; echo "doesnotexist.txt") | while read filepath; do scp "$filepath" "trip:~/tom/"; echo $?; done
doesnotexist.txt: No such file or directory
1
doesnotexist.txt: No such file or directory
1
```

What is going on here? I hope someone can help me clear this up. Thank you!

Edit:

After some more fiddling, it appears this has something to do with ZSH, as it works in a normal bash-shell.

Comment: Hm, I cannot reproduce this behaviour. With the delay, can you see on `trip` that the scp has happened? I.e., is it just to output to stdout of scp that's missing? On my end, I see the output from both scp calls, on success just like on failure.

Comment: Maybe we need more details: OS type and version, bash version, scp version, etc, so someone can try with an environment as close to yours as possible.

Comment: I have added some more info. I also tried it myself on another linux computer (basically executing this comment in the opposite direction), and indeed(!) it works as expected.

Comment: Could you try: `while read filepath; do scp "$filepath" "trip:~/tom/" <&-; done`?

Comment: @KamilCuk, I tried your suggestion: it gives the same result.

Comment: I tried some more and it actually looks like only happens in my ZSH shell. If I tried in the Terminal.app with just bash: it works. Then also in my Alacritty+tmux using bash. Feel a bit silly that I didn't try to exclude this before.

Comment: Some digging in the scp source revealed that the non-output is caused by this check returning false: https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/master/progressmeter.c#L81-L85. (I.e. the process group id of the current process being different from the owner of stdout?).

One difference between bash and zsh is that zsh runs while loops in the main shell process (which I gleaned from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/407254/414808)).

But this is as far as I am able to dig right now.

Comment: Turns out that running the whole while loop in a subshell does not have the problem:
`(echo "text.txt"; sleep 2; echo "text.txt") | (while read filepath; do scp "$filepath" "trip:~/tom/"; echo $?; done)`

Comment: Why don't you run as: (echo "text.txt"; echo "text.txt") | while read filepath; do scp "$filepath" "trip:~/tom/"; echo $?; sleep 2; done ? It seems safer than taking the output of sleep as input for scp by pipes. It might seem sleep is not doing any output in your version but flushing buffer of shells always should be considered.  sleep that you use in your way does not mimic behavior of fswatch.

Comment: @mihi thanks, I didn't try that variant and I think it's a fine workaround.

Comment: How about posting that as an answer and accepting it, so the question doesn't stay open as "unanswered"?

Answer (score 0):

Running the whole while loop in a subshell does not have the problem. This seems work:

```
(echo "text.txt"; sleep 2; echo "text.txt") | (while read filepath; do scp "$filepath" "trip:~/tom/"; echo $?; done)
```

Some digging in the scp source revealed that the non-output is caused by this check returning false: [progressmeter.c#L81-L85](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/b7ffbb17e37f59249c31f1ff59d6c5d80888f689/progressmeter.c#L81-L85)

```c
static int
can_output(void)
{
    return (getpgrp() == tcgetpgrp(STDOUT_FILENO));
}
```

(I.e. the process group id of the scp process suddenly being different from the "foreground process group on the terminal associated to stdout").

One difference between bash and zsh is that zsh runs while loops in the main shell process, while bash does not (which I gleaned from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/407254/414808)). But this is as far as I am able to dig right now.